# How to save complete html page with frames/iframes included?

Tags: html, ruby, iframe, web-scraping, watir

During the web scraping I want to save current page's html to a file for later debug. `browser.html` helps in most cases, but when the page contains an iframe/frame, it's content is not returned in `browser.html`, I have to get it separately with something like `browser.iframe.html` 
There are also cases when inside an iframe is another iframe. I can find every frame recursively and save its content, but separated files won't be very useful because I don't know the exact structure of the page.

For example I have the following page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
  <frameset cols="50%,20%,30%">
     <frame name="left" src="/html/left_frame.htm" />
     <frame name="right" src="/html/right_frame.htm" />
     <noframes>
       <body>
          Your browser does not support frames.
       </body>
     </noframes>
     <frame src="http://example.com"/>
  </frameset>
</html>
```

I want to save it to file using watir. Any ideas?

Comment: user is asking for assistance with an activity that that violates terms and conditions of the site he is accessing (or in this case provided as an example)

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden That was true before the edit, but even so doesn't appear to be sufficient reason for closure: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275031/238886

Answer (score 1):

Frames act much like a completely separate web page, and while you can see the content as it appears in the rendered document and the dom, contents of a frame are not technically part of the html for a page.  You can see this in the browser, right click the main doc and view html, then compare that to what you get right clicking content that is in a frame and viewing html.

To write all the html out to files, you are likely going to need to make a method that writes out html of a frame, looks for other frames, and calls the same method recursively on any frames found inside.

Alternativly maybe look at a gem like nokogiri that is designed to parse html, it might have better methods for this sort of thing, or existing examples for how to do what you want

Comment: Nokogiri parses raw HTML string. The question is how to obtain the complete HTML. Getting content of each frame is also easy, but concatenating them is already a problem. Frame can be nested under a specific html tag. Also there can be frames inside frames.

PS Headless browser, no right clicks.