# Watir get browser html with iframe content included

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, watir

Is there a way to get the html of the whole page with rendered iframes html also included? I know you can access browser html like so.

```
 browser.html
```

but that only prints the current's DOM html, without the iframe contents. I also know the iframe content can be retrieve like so .

```
 browser.iframe(index: 0).html
```

But is there a way to get the browser page contents, with all the iframes content rendered included also; the reason why I'm asking is because some iframes might have other iframes embedded and so on. So it becomes cumbersome to parse.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save complete html page with frames/iframes included?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476029/how-to-save-complete-html-page-with-frames-iframes-included)